# How to create a post-processing effect to render on top of the screen in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to create a global post-processing effect to render as an overlay on the screen in Android, in other words, I want to access the pixels on the screen and change them in realtime to create the desired effect, however I could not find anything about this in the documentation, any help?

The effect should draw on top of everything else, not just inside the app.

Comment: you do that by overriding onDraw(Canvas c) in the view you wanna add the effect

Comment: Does it render on top of everything? I don't want the effect only in the app, it's a global overlay.

Comment: aaaa no, system overlays had been disabled for a while since it exposes sensitive user data